# Calendar Module Tag {date} variable not correct

Tags: calendar

I have setup a calendar using the native calendar module tag. The date variable {date format="%F %Y"} renders as APRIL 2013. Shouldn't it be rendering as May 2013? The url points to /2013/05 as the last two segments. Any logic behind this that I missed?

Cheers

edited here is the template code:

```
{exp:channel:calendar channel="daily_posts"}

        <table class="calendarBG" border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" summary="My Calendar">
            <tr class="calendarHeader">
                <th>
                    <div class="calendarMonthLinks"><a href="{previous_path='month/index'}">&lt;&lt;</a>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th colspan="5">
                    <h2>{date format="%F %Y"}</h2>
                 </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="calendarMonthLinks">
                        <a class="calendarMonthLinks" href="{next_path='month/index'}">&gt;&gt;</a>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            {calendar_heading}
            <th class="calendarDayHeading">{lang:weekday_long}</th>
            {/calendar_heading}
            </tr>
            {calendar_rows}
                {row_start}<tr>{/row_start}
                {if entries}
                    <td class='{switch}' align='center'>
                        {entries}
                            <a href="/story/{entry_id}">
                                <span class="date">{entry_date format="%j %M %d"}</span>
                                <span class="day">{day_number}</span>
                                <img src="/assets/img/painting-nails.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        {/entries}
                    </td>
                {/if}
                {if not_entries}
                    <td class='{switch}' align='center'>{day_number}</td>
                {/if}
                {if blank}
                    <td class='calendarBlank'>{day_number}</td>
                {/if}
                {row_end}</tr>{/row_end}
            {/calendar_rows}
         </table>
    {/exp:channel:calendar}
```

Comment: Can you post some or all of your template so we can see a bit more detail? It sounds like it SHOULD be May since the date variable is supposed to be today's date, but without seeing the template it's a bit hard to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Out of interest, what do you get if you try the url 2013/05/01 ?

Answer (score 1):

When testing the site on a dev server the month displayed correctly. So I assume the issue was related to me local setup.